# How much disk size require to install reactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have limited size on disk. I want to be sure no unexpected error comes while installing due to disk space. Please help. Thank you and appreciated

Comment: Can you approve this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49892027/1946016

Answer (score 4):

```
$ npm init
$ npm install react
$ du -sk ./node_modules/
6820    ./node_modules/
```

~7MB

Comment: This is correct answer, react library is no bigger than few MBs

Answer (score 2):

I got these stats from `yarn why react`, And I'm using React 15.6.2

```
yarn why v1.5.1
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "react"...?
[2/4]   Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4]   Finding dependency...
[4/4]   Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "react@15.6.2"
info Has been hoisted to "react"
info This module exists because it's specified in "dependencies".
info Disk size without dependencies: "332MB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "2.18GB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "6.42GB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 13
✨  Done in 1.26s.
```

And for the newest React version 16.3.2:

```
yarn why v1.5.1
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "react"...?
[2/4]   Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4]   Finding dependency...
[4/4]   Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "react@16.3.2"
info Has been hoisted to "react"
info This module exists because it's specified in "dependencies".
info Disk size without dependencies: "52MB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "1.01GB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "5.14GB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 4
✨  Done in 0.26s.
```

So if you have `yarn` installed globally in your machine, you can easily figure this out with `yarn why npm-package-name` command.

You can read more from the doc: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/why/

Comment: That's more space than some of the indie games occupy .... Interesting

Comment: Don't know if it's a bug from yarn or something. But with react 18, the size is greatly reduced, with the Disk size with transitive dependencies: "448KB"